# How can I preserve the format while exporting data from excel to evernote

Tags: xml, excel, vba, import, evernote

I have the following code in excel which imports the data from every row and column into a single note for every row.

But it doesn't formats the data as it is in excel but just prints the cell contents as it is.

This is how it looks now when I impor the .enex file

[image: Screenshot of the imported data]
This is how it looks in excel.

[image]

> Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub OutputNotesXML()

Dim iRow As Long

Close #1
With ActiveSheet
    'For iRow = 2 To 2
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\evernote-import.enex" For Output As #1
        Print #1, "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "?>"
        Print #1, "<!DOCTYPE en-export SYSTEM " & Chr(34) & "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export.dtd" & Chr(34) & ">"
        Print #1, "<en-export export-date=" & Chr(34) & "20120202T073208Z" & Chr(34) & " application=" & Chr(34) & "Evernote/Windows" & Chr(34) & " version=" & Chr(34) & "4.x" & Chr(34) & ">"

    For iRow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Print #1, "<note><title>"
        Print #1, .Cells(iRow, "A").Value 'Title
        Print #1, "</title><content><![CDATA[<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "?>"
        Print #1, "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM " & Chr(34) & "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd" & Chr(34) & ">"
        Print #1, "<en-note style=" & Chr(34) & "word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;" & Chr(34) & ">"
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "B").Value) & vbNewLine 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "C").Value) & vbNewLine 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "D").Value) & vbNewLine 'Note

        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "E").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "F").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "G").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "H").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "I").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "J").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "K").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "L").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "M").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "N").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "O").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "P").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "Q").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "R").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "S").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "T").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "U").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "V").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "W").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "X").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "Y").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "Z").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "AA").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "AB").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, CBr(.Cells(iRow, "AC").Value) 'Note
        Print #1, "</en-note>]]></content><created>"




        'Print #1, .Cells(iRow, "D").Text 'Created Date in Evernote Time Format...
        'To get the evernote time, first convert your time to Zulu/UTC time.
        'Put this formula in Column D: =C2+TIME(6,0,0) where 6 is the hours UTC is ahead of you.
        'Then right click on your date column, select format, then select custom. Use this custom code: yyyymmddThhmmssZ
        Print #1, "</created><updated>201206025T000001Z</updated></note>"
    Next iRow
    Print #1, "</en-export>"
    Close #1

End With

End Sub

Function CBr(val) As String
    'parse hard breaks into to HTML breaks
    CBr = Replace(val, Chr(13), "")
    CBr = Replace(CBr, "&", "&amp;")
End Function

'I modified this code from Marty Zigman's post here: http://blog.prolecto.com/2012/01/31/importing-excel-data-into-evernote-without-a-premium-account/
```

Comment: you will most likely need to wrap the rows in a some format that tells the xml it's a table.

Comment: Yes I need that exactly but I don't know the formatting syntax for the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents for an Evernote note are in [ENML](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php), which is a superset of xHTML. You'll see that the list of [permitted elements](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php#permitted) includes tags like `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`, so you can use those to construct an html table for the note content.

An alternative solution would be to do it via CSS. The caveat there is that the CSS will have to go in the `style` attribute for each element, as an inline style. Note that the `<br/>` tag is also supported.

Comment: Thanks for the info I just want to `Print` every line on new line in the note can you help with this I am just so new to this can't catch up I tried adding `<div>` tags but I get too many errors.

Comment: Thanks . So adding `"<br>"` : simply as a string in `Print #1, "<br>" & CBr(.Cells(iRow, "E").Value) & "</br>"` prints it on new line and that solves one problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you start by manually building a Note in Evernote that looks just like you want it to, and then export that Note to ENEX.  You can then examine the ENEX file to see how things need to be formatted.

One key thing I have noticed is that the Evernote app itself uses the HTML `<div>` tag extensively, rather than `<p>` or `<br>`, to achieve lines without spaces between the lines.

If you want the EN Note to display the data as table, like in Excel, then you will need to use the HTML `<table>` tags in your output.